# Searching 2 Tables for a unique entry, then changing the data

Tags: php, mysql

The goal is to search two similar tables for a single line of data.

```
UPDATE
regusers_test AS rt
INNER JOIN
alt_toon_test AS att
ON
att.`toonname` = rt.`toonname`
SET
rt.`server` = CASE WHEN rt.`username`='$user' AND rt.`server`='$oserver' AND rt.`toonname`='$otoon' THEN '$server' ELSE rt.`server`
att.`server` = CASE WHEN att.`username`='$user' AND att.`server`='$oserver' AND att.`toonname`='$otoon' THEN '$server' ELSE att.`server`
WHERE
(
rt.`username`='$user' AND rt.`server`='$oserver' AND rt.`toonname`='$otoon'
)
OR
(
att.`username`='$user' AND att.`server`='$oserver' AND att.`toonname`='$otoon'
)
```

But i keep getting:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your mySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'att.'server'=Case When att.'username'='$user'...
```

I did a lot of google searches over the weekend and couldn't find a solution. Hopefully someone here knows what's up.

Comment: Do you need a comma between the two fields you're trying to set?

Comment: Echo your query. I'm sure the errors will be obvious.

Answer (score 0):

SET requires , between assignments.

EDIT Fixed your query:

```
UPDATE
regusers_test AS rt
INNER JOIN
alt_toon_test AS att
ON
att.`toonname` = rt.`toonname`
SET
rt.`server` = CASE WHEN rt.`username`='$user' AND rt.`server`='$oserver' AND rt.`toonname`='$otoon' THEN '$server' ELSE rt.`server`,
att.`server` = CASE WHEN att.`username`='$user' AND att.`server`='$oserver' AND att.`toonname`='$otoon' THEN '$server' ELSE att.`server`
WHERE
(
rt.`username`='$user' AND rt.`server`='$oserver' AND rt.`toonname`='$otoon'
)
OR
(
att.`username`='$user' AND att.`server`='$oserver' AND att.`toonname`='$otoon'
)
```

Comment: I completely copied and pasted the fix that Aragon0 gave me and i still get the same message. mySQL version is 5.0

Comment: DERP, forgot to put "END" at the end of each column case

Answer (score 0):

You just missed the `,` between columns near

```
SET
rt.`server` = CASE WHEN rt.`username`='$user' AND rt.`server`='$oserver' AND rt.`toonname`='$otoon' THEN '$server' ELSE rt.`server` END ,
att.`server` = CASE WHEN att.`username`='$user' AND att.`server`='$oserver' AND att.`toonname`='$otoon' THEN '$server' ELSE att.`server` END
```

Comment: See my updated answer there is an `END` missing in the `CASE`